# name 'cache' is not defined django

Tags: django, django-views

```
class CourseListView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'eschool/course/list.html'

    def get(self, request, subject=None):
        subjects = cache.get('all_subjects')
        if not subjects:
            subjects = Subject.objects.annotate(total_courses=Count('courses'))
            cache.set('all_subjects', subjects)
        all_courses = Course.objects.annotate(total_modules=Count('modules'))

        if subject:
            subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, slug=subject)
            key = f'subject_{subject.id}_courses'
            courses = cache.get(key)

            if not courses:
                courses = all_courses.filter(subject=subject)
                cache.set(key, courses)
        else:
            courses = cache.get('all_courses')
            if not courses:
                courses = all_courses
                cache.set('all_courses', courses)
        return self.render_to_response({
            'subjects': subjects,
            'subject': subject,
            'courses': courses
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add this:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
```